# redirect and index.php to automatically instance php classes

Tags: php, class, redirect, instance

I would like to create an apache redirect of all .php requests in a specific directory to index.php. In index php I would like to include the file and create an instance of the class.

for example:

mySite.com/directory/classname.php

would be re-directed to mySite.com/directory/index.php

index.php would automatically include_once classname.php

and create instance of classname if the file exists.

I don't want to lose get or post values.
I only want .php files redirected

Here is what I have figured out so far, based on understanding of manual & others questions

in .htaccess

```
## turn on re-write engine
RewriteEngine on 

## base url
RewriteBase / 

## ignore files??
## RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 

## ignore directories
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

## not index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^index.php [NC] 

## if file does not exist then ignore
RewriteRule  ^(.*)$ index.php?param=$1 [QSA,L]
```

in index.php

```
$path = $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"];
$path = basename($path, ".php"); 

include_once $path;
$path = new $path;
```

Comment: Please tell me you've taken appropriate steps to avoid inclusion of arbitrary files.

Comment: still working through the details. can  $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]; 
be compromised?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteRule \.(php)$ index.php [L,NC]
```